# Map JSON to NSDictionary in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, mapping, nsdictionary

I have the following JSON from a Web service:

```
[
    "{
       "count":2,
       "offers":{
          "0":{
             "nodeID":"654321",
             "publicationDate":"1396272408",
             "title":"My first title",
             "locations":"New York City"
          },
          "1":{
             "nodeID":"123456",
             "publicationDate":"1396272474",
             "title":"My second title",
             "locations":"San Diego"
          }
       },
       "error":"null",
       "result":"success"
    }"
]
```

I need to map this JSON to a `NSDictionary`. How can I do that?

I already tried the following

```
NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&localError];
```

but it only gives me a dictionary with one object in it. I need to access all the fields of the JSON such as `"count"`, `"offers"` etc. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You JSON output is not a dictionary but an array.

```
NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSarray *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&localError];

for(NSDictionary *dict in parsedObject) {
   NSNumber *count = [dict objectForKey:@"count"];

}
```

But the offer node is just weird, this would be better as an array.

Comment: Is this actually valid JSON except the weird curly braces? The square brackets encapsulating the JSON object look also weird, don't they?

Comment: If you are only returning one object, then yes. IN case of you example it does look weird and unneeded.

Answer (score 0):

Get your data in this form ... Your json Give error of ".....

```
   [
      {
           "count": 2,
           "offers":
           {
           "0": {
                     "nodeID": "654321",
                     "publicationDate": "1396272408",
                     "title": "Myfirsttitle",
                     "locations": "NewYorkCity"
                },
           "1": {
                     "nodeID": "123456",
                     "publicationDate": "1396272474",
                     "title": "Mysecondtitle",
                     "locations": "SanDiego"
                }
           },
           "error": "null",
           "result": "success"
      }
   ]
```

You get data In  Array [ having Dictionary in dictionary ....